# Increasing Goldbach partitions

Tags: code-golf, number-theory, decision-problem, primes

The Goldbach conjecture states that:

> [every even number that is greater than 2 is the sum of two primes.](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GoldbachConjecture.html)

We will consider a Goldbach partition of a number **n** to be a pair of two primes adding to **n**.  We are concerned with numbers is *of increasing Goldbach partition*. We measure the size of a number's Goldbach partitions by the size of the smallest prime in all of that number's partitions.  A number is of increasing partition if this size is greater than the size of all smaller even numbers.

## Task

Given an even integer **n > 2**, determine if **n** is of increasing Goldbach partition, and output two unique values, one if it is and one if it is not.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so you should aim to minimize the number of bytes in your source code.

[OEIS A025018](http://oeis.org/A025018)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61491/discussion-between-olm-man-and-lembik).

Comment: It is good question, that is difficult to understand. I edited it to simplify the wording. Please check it, and if all is correct apply changes.

Comment: @ЕвгенийНовиков I found your edit more confusing than the original.  I have rejected it.  Perhaps we can discuss a way to make this clearer [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61491/discussion-between-olm-man-and-lembik).

Comment: The worked examples are still very confusing - they seem to pull numbers out of nowhere, and each of the comparisons is expressed differently without explaining *why* certain numbers are used. If you already know the answer, you can figure it out . . . which I did by going back to the first paragraph, ignoring the examples until it was clear, then figuring out how the examples were constructed. Perhaps some tabular structure would help, also including 10 would probably help

Comment: @NeilSlater Thanks for the feedback.  I've removed the examples entirely because I think they were doing more harm than good.  I think the challenge is clear from the explanation, and the examples only complicate things.  If the explanation *is not sufficient* I would be more than happy to expand or clarify on that, however I don't think I will be adding the examples back in because they seem to be the greatest source of confusion so far.

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 12 bytes

```
ÆRðfạṂ
Ç€M⁼W
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AS0A0v9qZWxsef//w4ZSw7Bm4bqh4bmCCsOH4oKsTeKBvFf/NHI1MDBtMsOHw5BmWf8)

#### How it works

```
Ç€M⁼W   Main link. Argument: n

Ç€      Map the helper link over [1, ..., n].
  M     Get all indices of the maximum.
    W   Wrap; yield [n].
   ⁼    Test the results to both sides for equality.


ÆRðfạṂ  Helper link. Argument: k

ÆR      Prime range; get all primes in R := [1, ..., k].
  ð     Begin a dyadic chain with arguments R and k.
    ạ   Absolute difference; yield k-p for each p in R.
   f    Filter; keep the q in R such that q = k-p for some p in R.
     Ṃ  Take the minimum.
        This yields 0 if the array is empty.
```

Answer (score 4):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 154 bytes

```php
for(;$n++<$a=$argn;$i-1?:$p[]=$n)for($i=$n;--$i&&$n%$i;);foreach($p as$x)foreach($p as$y)if(!$r[$z=$x+$y]){$r[$z]=$x;$l[]=$z<$a?$x:0;};echo$r[$a]>max($l);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY3BCoMwGIPve4pNMmkpBefR384HEQ9FdC24WvRSHXv2rnrbLckXEm98rBtv/AV6eTmVlWWRURznhRGcEDW0OgnBykdTwbedguNHATYpkhI2z@HusMQp5YPuDYO/6hWB//uN25HdsLTYFYLA1vHP6dJmIEzH9p4uG4SqoC8NvZkPrrvnWweGiVOMPw)

Expanded

```php
for(;$n++<$a=$argn;$i-1?:$p[]=$n) # loop through all integers till input if is prime add to array 
  for($i=$n;--$i&&$n%$i;);
foreach($p as$x) #loop through prime array
  foreach($p as$y) #loop through prime array 
    if(!$r[$z=$x+$y]){
      $r[$z]=$x; # add only one time lower value for a sum of $x+$y 
      $l[]=$z<$a?$x:0;}; # add lower value if sum is lower then input
echo$r[$a]>max($l); # Output 1 if lower value for sum of input is greater then all lower values of all numbers under input
```

[Try it online! Check for all numbers till 1000](https://tio.run/##ZY4xa8MwEIX3/IrWvAYJy@CUTr64HkqGLu3SLTFBBMUWuLK4uKAkpH/dlQ0dSrd7d@/e93zrx3XlW78wzD3v2fieB@sa8b3Zv71/vL5sJC2OPRt9aAVr1xjxpFZ5nqtHqU/Q3Dh5/XInMwh4hU6BFZykMf4IgkvTNXQ5@wg2W1UF/LYuo2UywMaJsgx2uYR7gCVJvzD4uwgI8q8@S3sU9@AtLiVCinMtr7OKmYHQTdmXiKwQipxuZA5tP911/fypg0AXq/3fVclumDvuXFIkCd3GHw)

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript (ES6), 135 bytes

Uses a similar logic as [Jörg's PHP answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/129627/58563).

```js
(n,P=[...Array(n).keys()].filter(n=>(p=n=>n%--x?p(n):x==1)(x=n)))=>P.map(p=>P.map(q=>a[q+=p]=a[q]||(m=q<n&&p>m?p:m,p)),a=[m=0])&&a[n]>m
```

#### Demo

```js
let f =

(n,P=[...Array(n).keys()].filter(n=>(p=n=>n%--x?p(n):x==1)(x=n)))=>P.map(p=>P.map(q=>a[q+=p]=a[q]||(m=q<n&&p>m?p:m,p)),a=[m=0])&&a[n]>m

console.log(
  JSON.stringify(
    [...Array(310).keys()].filter(n => f(n))
  )
)
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3: <strike>156</strike> <strike>151</strike> <strike>142</strike> <strike>138</strike> <strike>136</strike> 128 bytes

```
r=range
m=lambda n:min(x for x in r(2,n+1)if all(o%i for o in[x,n-x]for i in r(2,o)))
f=lambda n:m(n)>max(map(m,r(2,n,2)))or n<5
```

(thanks to OP)

(thanks to @Rod)(again)(and again)

Comment: @Olmman do you like it?

Comment: @Rod since `max` with key returns element with maximal value after applying key, I had to add function application but it's nonetheless shorter.

Comment: @Rod and I can't take your suggestions as for `range` since `n` is bounded inside `lambda`.

Comment: @enedil Indeed, but for the max, you can use `max(map(m,r[::2]))`

Comment: @Rod ughh, there's gotta be a few bytes to save, to be the shortest of all nonesoteric languages! (except switching to Python2!)

Comment: Okay, one last tip and I will stop bothering you : The `p`function can be inserted on `m` as `m=lambda n:min(x for x in r(2,n+1)if all(o%i for o in[x,n-x]for i in r(2,o)))`

Comment: You don't need to name `f` and thus can save 2 bytes by removing the `f=`.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3: <strike>204</strike> 196 bytes

Bytes saved thanks to: Olm Man

```
from itertools import*
m=lambda g:min([x for x in product([n for n in range(2,g)if all(n%i for i in range(2,n))],repeat=2)if sum(x)==g][0])
i=lambda g:1if all(m(g)>m(x)for x in range(4,g,2))else 0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY1BDoIwEEX3nmI2JjOGBaArk3oRwqJKqZO006aUBE9fBY26ff/lv/jI9yDHUsYUPHA2KYfgJmAfQ8qHnVdO@@ugwZ49C3YLjCHBAiwQUxjmW8ZONiYrS1qswbayxCNo51D2vK38vwpRXyUTjc6qXc1p9riQUrbv6p52/Is2nx@Pli6r9M2/z06VrVoi4yYDdYmJJSNj80LlCQ)

Comment: A few tips,  most builtin functions like `min` and `all` can take generators as arguments, this means `min([...])` can be shortened to `min(...)` and the same with all.  You also can get rid of some spaces, particularly the space in `import *` and any space after braces, I see you have one after `range(g)` and one before `[i for i in ...`, neither are necessary.

Comment: ^That's awesome, I didn't know that

Comment: Also you can make your prime check a little shorter by changing it to `all(n%i for i in range(2,g))`, but you have to change `range(g)` to `range(1,g)` because this gives a false positive on 1.